# Is it always necessary to either stem/lemmatize words when working with TF-IDF?

Tags: nlp, tf-idf, stemming, lemmatization

I'm using TF-IDF along with cosine similarity in order to compute document similarity. I was wondering if it's always necessary to stem/lemmatize the words in the document. Are there times where based on the task, it's better not to stem/lemmatize?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think the short answer is "Yes, there are." It all depends on your use case, occasionally you might want to find full words if their semantic meanings change between stems for instance, or you might want to preserve information that gets lost as a term gets converted into a lemma. You might want to start with understanding at what level you wish to compare similarities and if these semantics make a difference in your use case or not, and go from there. Hope this helps!